# WPF: How to automatically close Popup for corner cases where `StaysOpen="False"` alone is not enough?

Tags: wpf, popup

I have created a custom time picker control that is opening in a `Popup` centered on a button and it is working great. The only issue I haven't been able to fix is that when, while the `Popup` is open and the user either moves the window that contains my control (by dragging its title bar) or when they scroll outside of my control, the `Popup` does not close and just stays in its original location.

I have set `StaysOpen="False"` and this is working great for all but the two cases mentioned above: Clicking anywhere in my application (except for the title bar area) will cause the popup to close.

According to the docs:

> When `StaysOpen` is `false`, the `Popup` control intercepts all mouse and keyboard events to determine when one of these events occurs outside the `Popup` control.

However, this does not seem to mean what I thought it would: When I assign an event handler to the `Popup`'s `MouseWheel`, `PreviewMouseWheel`, `MouseDown`, etc. this will never fire for any mouse activity outside of the `Popup`. Probably the docs mean it is intercepting them internally only? If so, it is failing to catch these corner cases...

I have already read through a ton of accepted answers on this topic here but they all either have no effect for me (for whatever reason) or they are handling this by actually capturing the mouse events outside the control's code and then tell the control to close its `Popup`. This is not an option for me as I want my control to be reusable on any parent without requiring the consumer to add code for closing the `Popup` on mouse activity... Everything that is required to get this working needs to be part of my control, either its code or its style/template.

I have kind of come up with a solution to the scrolling problem by walking the visual tree up from my control until I find a `ScrollViewer` and then attach myself to its `ScrollChanged` event and that seems to work at least for simple cases but it still feels kinda hacky...

I have not had any idea on how to deal with the title bar issue...

Any more ideas or pointers?

Here's a simplified example that exhibits the same problem:

Class:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PopupPartName, Type = typeof(Popup))]
public class PopupButton : ButtonBase
{
    public const string PopupPartName = "PART_Popup";

    private Popup _popup;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _popup = GetTemplateChild(PopupPartName) as Popup;
        _popup.Opened += OnPopupOpened;
        _popup.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        _popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
        _popup.IsOpen = false;
    }

    private void OnPopupOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _popup.PreviewMouseWheel += OnPopupMouseWheel;
        _popup.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnPopupMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void OnPopupClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _popup.PreviewMouseWheel -= OnPopupMouseWheel;
        _popup.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= OnPopupMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void OnPopupMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        _popup.IsOpen = _popup.IsMouseOver;
    }

    private void OnPopupMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _popup.IsOpen = _popup.IsMouseOver;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PopupButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:PopupButton}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16 8" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PopupButton}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="TheButton"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                  TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                                   Width="{Binding ElementName=TheButton, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                   Height="100"
                                   AllowsTransparency="True"
                                   Focusable="True"
                                   Placement="Center"
                                   PopupAnimation="Fade"
                                   StaysOpen="False">
                                <Border Background="DarkBlue">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="Whatever" />
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Height="2048">
            <TextBox Width="200"
                     Margin="32"
                     Text="Whatever" />

            <local:PopupButton Margin="32"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top"
                               Background="Blue"
                               Content="Click here for popup"
                               Foreground="White"
                               Style="{StaticResource PopupButtonStyle}" />

            <Button Margin="32"
                    Padding="16 8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="Something else to click on" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Steps:

1. Click the blue button
2. Move the window by dragging the title bar - OR:
3. Scroll the window content, either using the scrollbar or the mouse wheel.

-> The popup will not close in those cases and breakpoints in the `OnPopupMouseWheel()` or `OnPopupMouseLeftButtonDown()` methods will not be hit unless you scroll or click *inside* of the popup.

Just for completeness: My code currently needs to run under .NET Framework 4.8 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird that you report that the input events are not raised. This is not normal.

**Edit**
After the poster updated the question to provide a more detailed example it became apparent that the `Popup` was opened wrong, causing a mouse capture issue that impacted the `Popup` behavior (see explanation below). After fixing this the `popup` behaves normally and doesn't require tracking of the parent window's location any more. Clicking outside the `Popup` while `Popup.StaysOpen` is `false` now behaves correctly and closes the `Popup` without further action.

<strike>Creating your custom `Popup` and then overriding the relevant mouse event handlers will do the trick.

To detect window drag you must get the owning `Window` instance and observe the `Window.LocationChanged` event</strike>:

**MyPopup.cs**

```cs
public class MyPopup : Popup
{
  protected override void OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseWheel(e);
    this.IsOpen = this.StaysOpen || this.Child.IsMouseOver;
  }
}
```

---

Now that you have posted an example implementation, I can tell for sure that the issue is not .NET version related. It's just the way you handle the `Popup`. You have essentially broken the behavior of the `Popup`.

Using a simple `Button` or `ButtonBase` and handling mouse down/up events to open the `Popup` (or to react on a button click in general) can be problematic as the `ButtonBase` does some mouse capture handling internally.

The `ButtonBase` has a `ButtonBase.IsPressed` state. To ensure that the `ButtonBase` doesn't miss the release state it has to capture the mouse. After `ButtonBase` is done handling the `IsPressed` state it converts the mouse down/up event to the `ButtonBase.Click` event.
When this event is raised the mouse capture is finally released and other elements like your `Popup` can continue to receive mouse events like the `UIElement.MouseWheel` event.

Now, the problematic part is that the `Popup` itself requires to acquire the mouse capture. It requires the capture in order to realize the `Popup.StaysOpen` behavior. When you open the `Popup` while the `ButtonBase` still holds the capture, the `Popup` can't capture mouse too. This results in the odd behavior you observe, for example clicking outside the `Popup` won't close it.

This means you must always handle the `ButtopnBase.Click` event if you want to react to a click on the button. `UIElement.MouseDown` does not represent a click. In your case, you would simply override the `ButtonBase.OnClick` method (and remove the `ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonDown` override.

My example was overriding the event handler in the `Popup` class. My example enables the `MyPopup` to control itself while your example the behavior is externally controlled. From a design perspective I recommend implementing the behavior by extending the `Popup` the way I did with `MyPopup`.

However, to avoid the hassle of caring about the mouse click handling of the `Button` I recommend to use a `ToggleButton` (as it is usually done). For example, framework controls like the `ComboBox` use `ToggleButton` too. The key is to handle the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property or preferably bind it to the `Popup.IsOpen` property.
Introducing the `ToggleButton`and the related binding makes handling the `Popup.Opened` and `Popup.Closed` event redundant to further simplify the implementation of `PopupButton`.

Additionally, you don't have to handle mouse clicks outside the `Popup` as the `Popup` will close by default when `Popup.StaysOpen` is set to `false`. This makes the handling of the `LostFocus` event unnecessary.
You only have to take care of the `MouseWheel` event.

And because of the acquired mouse capture of the `Popup` you must also observe the `Popup.IsMouseDirectlyOver` property instead of `Popup.IsMouseOver` (because of the captured mouse `IsMouseOver` would always return `true` while the `Popup` has captured the mouse, even when the mouse is not over the `Popup` while the `MouseWheel` event is raised).

The `MousWheel` event is only raised for the `Popup` while it is opened and therefore is hooked into a visual tree. Additionally, the `Popup` is a child of the `PopupButton` as it is defined inside its `ControlTemplate` - the Popup can't live longer than the `PopupButton`. This makes unsubscribing from the `MousWheel` events on `Popup.Closed` redundant and allows to further simplify the code of `PopupButton`.

Just as a note: you can consider to mark the `MouseWheel` event as handled (swallow it) instead of closing the `Popup`. This would mean that the user can't scroll anything outside thePopup`until it is closed.   This is how the`ComboBox` is behaving, for instance.

Your fixed and improved code could look as follows:

**PopupButton.cs**
`PopupButton` now extends `ToggleButton` (instead of `ButtonBase`).
Because we open the `Popup` correctly now, we allow it to operate properly. We no longer have to care about losing the focus or mouse clicks outside the `Popup`.
Now, we only have to take care of the `PreviewMouseWheel` event:

```cs
public class PopupButton : ToggleButton
{
  public const string PopupPartName = "PART_Popup";

  private Popup _popup;

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    _popup = GetTemplateChild(PopupPartName) as Popup;

    // We must always anticipate a template override that doesn't 
    // provide the template part or doesn't name the part correctly. 
    // In this case GetTemplateChild returns NULL.
    if (_popup != null)
    {
      _popup.PreviewMouseWheel += OnPopupMouseWheel;
    }
  }

  private void OnPopupMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
    if (_popup != null)
    {
      _popup.IsOpen = _popup.Child.IsMouseOver;
    }
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PopupButton}">
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="16 8" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PopupButton}">
        <Grid>
          <Border x:Name="TheButton"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
          </Border>

          <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                 IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Templatedparent}, Path= IsChecked}"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=TheButton, Path=ActualWidth}"
                 Height="100"
                 AllowsTransparency="True"
                 Focusable="True"
                 Placement="Center"
                 PopupAnimation="Fade"
                 StaysOpen="False">
            <Border Background="DarkBlue">
              <TextBox Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Whatever" />
            </Border>
          </Popup>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does indeed resolve the issue with moving the window. However, it does nothing for the scrolling issue (or generally capturing mouse events outside of the `Popup`). Could it make a difference that my project is still using .NET Framework 4.8 while you appear to be using something more recent (judging by your use of a nullable reference type)? I should probably try to reproduce this with a simplified example for illustration, so I could post some code here...

Comment: I don't think this is related to the old .NET version you are using. I can reproduce the issue that scrolling outside the `Popup` will not move the focus away to close it. But the posted example solves it for me. It would be really helpful if you could post a really small and as simple as possible example in your question so that I or others can review it. Probably you are provoking a case that my solution does not cover.

Comment: I have just seen that you have updated your question. i will look into it later and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for providing the valuable information. This enabled me to identify what was going wrong. It's related to how you control the Popup (and not to the .NET version). I have updated my answer.

Comment: As an alternative behavior I would suggest marking the MouseWheel event as handled (`e.Handled = true`) and swallow it so that the user can't scroll outside the Popup while it's open. This is how the ComboBox behaves.

Comment: That is just such an incredibly awesome, well-explained answer! I wish I could upvote a seond time. :) Thanks! However, after implementing your suggested solution, I now have a few new problems with the mouse handling _inside_ the popup (obviously, in the actual code there's more than just a `TextBlock` there). I suspect analyzing these will require me adding more of my production code to the example. I will try to add that later this week.

Comment: Just to add a little more detail about the new problems before I extend the example code (or find a solution myself while doing it): After applying your solution, scrolling inside the popup closes it and clicking inside it makes it disappear on mouse down and reappear on mouse up. Inside the popup there are several more custom controls some of which override `OnMouseWheel()` and some of which override `OnMouseLeftButtonDown()`.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the `MouseWheel` issue when there is scrollable content hosted by the `Popup`. This is a simple hit test issue and can be fixed by checking `_popup.Child.IsMouseOver == true` (instead of `_popup.IsMouseDirectlyOver == true`.) `Popup` and `Popup.Child` anre two different visual trees. `Popup.Child` is hosted in its own `Window` instance that actually makes the popup window. Clicking inside the `Popup` does not produce any issues. So this must be related to what your mouse handlers are doing. Or are you using the `MyPopup`?

Comment: It would be nice if you create an example that integrates the new `PopupButton`  or `MyPopup` implementation and reproduces the exact issue.

Comment: The same fix must be applied to the `MyPopup`: `this.IsOpen = this.StaysOpen || this.Child.IsMouseOver;`.

Comment: Please note that after we found out that you were previously opening the `Popup` wrong, tracking the parent window's location is no longer required. I have modified the `MyPopup` accordingly and commented out the related code. Both versions must only handle the `PreviewMouseWheel` event.

Comment: I can already confirm that switching to `Child.IsMouseOver` fixed the scrolling inside the popup issue. Compiling a simplified example for the click issue will take some more time, but I don't think this is related to the original topic of the question anymore, so I'm happily accepting this already and will create a separate question if I cannot come up with a solution for the click issue. If I do find a solution myself I will simply post it here as a comment reply. Thanks again!

Comment: I've now had a little time to look at this again. Strangely, I can reproduce the clicking issue even with your unchanged example code (just the style and the button control, not the `MyPopup`). To reiterate: when I click anywhere inside the popup (except directly on the `TextBlock`) the popup will disappear on mouse-down and reappear on mouse-up... occasionally it will not reappear on mouse-up. If you're not seeing this then it must have something to do with how I'm putting the button on my main window... but there's nothing but a `ScrollViewer` and a `StackPanel` with the `PopupButton`...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I will review it tomorrow.

Comment: No need to hurry. I think I just found a "solution" that is good enough for now - at least for my production code. The custom controls I'm using in my popup already had handlers for mouse-down events. All I had to do to fix the click issue was to add an `e.Handled = true;`. As the controls cover the entire popup there are no spots left to click that would cause the issue. It'd still be interesting to know if there was a different approach that didn't require modifications of the popup's child controls (which might not always be feasible).

Comment: From a design perspective implementing the StaysOpen outside the Popup is a serious issue. It belongs to the Popup where the default behavior is implemented too. I will review the issue later and suggest a more general solution. But I think it would require to let go the PopupBotton in favor of an extended Popup or attached behavior. It makes no sense to implement such specialized logic in a Button. AtaysOpen is a Popup feature/behavior and not the behavior of an external button.

Comment: I have modified the `MyPopup` control of this answer. It exactly provides the behavior you want and in addition is a cleaner solution from a class design perspective.

Comment: Hm, either I'm still doing something wrong or I must have misunderstood what you're suggesting... With your example code as it exists in your answer at the time of this writing, I still have the problem that (without explicitly handling clicks inside the popup) the popup still disappears on mouse-down and (most of the time) reappears on mouse-up. Also, if I use the mouse wheel over an area of the popup that does itself not handle scrolling, then the button (along with any other content) will scroll away underneath the popup...